# Manually adding legend to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I made a graph of some GPS-data, where the colour of the path indicates in which habitat a bird was. I added a column to the df, with the desired colours as I wanted to set those manually per habitat type. This is the code I used (which works):

```
worldmap <- ne_countries(scale = 'medium', type = 'map_units',
                         returnclass = 'sf')
xlim <- c(min(random_bird$location.long)-0.1, max(random_bird$location.long)+0.1)
ylim <- c(min(random_bird$location.lat)-0.1, max(random_bird$location.lat)+0.1)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = worldmap) +
  coord_sf(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_path(aes(x = random_bird$location.long, y = random_bird$location.lat), colour = (random_bird$colour)) +
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude") + ggtitle(random_bird$colour_ring)+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This is a snip of the dataframe:

```
                timestamp location.long location.lat        habitat   colour colour_ring
 2022-08-26 14:34:33.000      2.732021     51.15316 Not classified    white       S.ROP
 2022-08-26 19:34:30.000      2.735457     51.15966     Intertidal cornsilk       S.ROP
 2022-08-27 03:34:31.000      2.741388     51.16101     Intertidal cornsilk       S.ROP
 2022-08-27 05:34:30.000      2.736342     51.15954     Intertidal cornsilk       S.ROP
 2022-08-27 08:34:56.000      2.728476     51.15704     Intertidal cornsilk       S.ROP
 2022-08-27 10:34:28.000      2.726892     51.15534     Intertidal cornsilk       S.ROP
 2022-08-27 11:34:28.000      2.726382     51.15453 Not classified    white       S.ROP
 2022-08-27 12:34:27.000      2.726405     51.15470 Not classified    white       S.ROP
 2022-08-27 17:34:32.000      2.723473     51.15557     Intertidal cornsilk       S.ROP
 2022-08-28 08:34:55.000      2.757212     51.16779     Intertidal cornsilk       S.ROP
```

Now I would like to **add a legend mapping the habitat types to the specified colour**, I tried using `scale_colour_manual()`, but can't seem to get it right. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a legend then map on aesthetics, i.e. move `color=...` inside aes. And as your color column already contains the colors use `scale_color_identity(guide="legend")` to add the colors and a legend. Additionally you have to add nice labels when going this way.

For this reason IMHO it would be easier to map `habitat` directly on the color aes and then use `scale_color_manual` to set your desired colors.

Moreover, using `random_bird$...` is strongly discouraged. Just use column names directly when mapping on aes and add the data for the `geom_path` via `data=random_bird`.

Note: I added a grey background to the legend keys to make the colors visible.

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)

worldmap <- ne_countries(
  scale = "medium", type = "map_units",
  returnclass = "sf"
)
xlim <- range(random_bird$location.long) + 0.1 * c(-1, 1)
ylim <- range(random_bird$location.lat) + 0.1 * c(-1, 1)

base <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = worldmap) +
  coord_sf(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", title = unique(random_bird$colour_ring)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.key = element_rect(fill = "grey80"))

base +
  geom_path(data = random_bird, aes(x = location.long, y = location.lat, colour = colour)) +
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

```r
pal <- random_bird |>
  dplyr::distinct(habitat, colour) |>
  tibble::deframe()

base +
  geom_path(data = random_bird, aes(x = location.long, y = location.lat, colour = habitat)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
random_bird <- structure(list(timestamp = c(
  " 2022-08-26 14:34:33.000", " 2022-08-26 19:34:30.000",
  "2022-08-27 03:34:31.000", "2022-08-27 05:34:30.000", "2022-08-27 08:34:56.000",
  "2022-08-27 10:34:28.000", "2022-08-27 11:34:28.000", "2022-08-27 12:34:27.000",
  "2022-08-27 17:34:32.000", "2022-08-28 08:34:55.000"
), location.long = c(
  2.732021,
  2.735457, 2.741388, 2.736342, 2.728476, 2.726892, 2.726382, 2.726405,
  2.723473, 2.757212
), location.lat = c(
  51.15316, 51.15966, 51.16101,
  51.15954, 51.15704, 51.15534, 51.15453, 51.1547, 51.15557, 51.16779
), habitat = c(
  "Not classified", "Intertidal", "Intertidal",
  "Intertidal", "Intertidal", "Intertidal", "Not classified", "Not classified",
  "Intertidal", "Intertidal"
), colour = c(
  "white", "cornsilk",
  "cornsilk", "cornsilk", "cornsilk", "cornsilk", "white", "white",
  "cornsilk", "cornsilk"
), colour_ring = c(
  "S.ROP", "S.ROP", "S.ROP",
  "S.ROP", "S.ROP", "S.ROP", "S.ROP", "S.ROP", "S.ROP", "S.ROP"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```